# How to prevent overfitting in Keras sequential model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras, text-classification

I am already adding dropout regularization. I am trying to build a multiclass text classification multilayer perceptron model.
My model:

```
model = Sequential([
                Dropout(rate=0.2, input_shape=features),
                Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
                Dropout(rate=0.2),
                Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
                Dropout(rate=0.2),
                Dense(units=16, activation='softmax')])
```

My model.summary():

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 20000)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                1280064
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 64)                4160
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 16)                1040
=================================================================
Total params: 1,285,264
Trainable params: 1,285,264
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Train on 6940 samples, validate on 1735 samples
```

I am getting:

```
Epoch 16/1000
 - 4s - loss: 0.4926 - acc: 0.8719 - val_loss: 1.2640 - val_acc: 0.6640
Validation accuracy: 0.6639769498140736, loss: 1.2639631692545559
```

The validation accuracy is ~20% less than the accuracy, and the validation loss is way higher than the training loss.

I am already using dropout regularization, and using epochs = 1000, batch size = 512 and early stopping on val_loss.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please also add a code how do you run *model.fit( ... )*.

Comment: Would also need how you are doing the preprocessing on training and validation data if any

Comment: @DanyloBaibak As I said, epochs = 1000, batch size = 512, verbose = 2, rest are just my local variables.

Comment: @VivekKumar, tokenized the text as unigrams and bigrams and vectorizing using tf-idf, then i SelectKBest 20,000 features

Comment: @AhmedElGohary, do you have some validation dataset? The easiest way is `model.fit( ...., validation_split=0.1)`

Comment: @DanyloBaibak Yes I do, the problem is that the validation accuracy is 65% while the accuracy is 85%

Comment: How big is your data set? Have you tried messing around with different epochs/batch sizes, as well as the learning rate?